# Replacement for the deprecated method java.sql.CallableStatement.getBigDecimal(int parameterIndex, int scale)

Tags: jdbc, java-8

I'm trying to replace this deprecated method, but the suggested replacement omits the `Scale` parameter.

The scale parameter seems critical to my application, but I'm unable to figure out an efficient way to retain the precision value.

In case of `ResultSet` object, however, the `setScale()` method is a saving grace, but there's no such method in `CallableStatement`. Can anyone please suggest an alternative?

Comment: Just call `getBigDecimal(int parameterIndex)` and then call `setScale()` on the resulting `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Why is the scale parameter critical to your application? That suggests that the scale as defined in the database is somehow not right for you?

Comment: Also, a result set has no `setScale()` method either (at least not in `java.sql.ResultSet`).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks for your response! I'm not sure about the reason, since I'm working on a legacy application. I just wish to avoid running into regression issues for the time being.
Meanwhile, how does having setScale() in a ResultSet matter? Isn't it good enough to have it while retrieving the specific field values? Could you pls explain this point?

Comment: There is no such thing as `setScale()` in a result set, so I have no clue what you mean with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As specified in the documentation of [`CallableStatement.getBigDecimal(int parameterIndex, int scale)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#getBigDecimal-int-int-):

> **Deprecated**. *use `getBigDecimal(int parameterIndex)` or `getBigDecimal(String parameterName)`*

Using `getBigDecimal(int)` or `getBigDecimal(String)`, will return the

> [..] the value of the designated JDBC `NUMERIC` parameter as a
>   `java.math.BigDecimal` object with as many digits to the right of the
>   decimal point as the value contains.

If you need to change the scale, then you need to use [`BigDecimal.setScale(int newScale, RoundingMode roundingMode)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale-int-java.math.RoundingMode-) (or one of its siblings). This is what most (if not all) JDBC drivers do anyway inside the deprecated `getBigDecimal(int parameterIndex, int scale)` method.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm properly understood,
Additional setScale it's not enough.
As example for:

```
BigDecimal.valueOf(100).setScale(2)
```

You get: 100.00

You have to use simple division:

```
BigDecimal.valueOf(100).setScale(scale).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(10^scale))
```

As example:

```
BigDecimal.valueOf(100).setScale(2).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(100))
```

It works the same as:

```
BigDecimal.valueOf(100, 2)
```

So,
For Your case:

```
cs.getBigDecimal(parameterIndex, scale);
```

should be equal to:

```
cs.getBigDecimal(parameterIndex).setScale(scale).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.pow(10,scale));
```